# What does "stub" means in testing?

Tags: android, testing, stub, android-espresso

Can someone please explain me what "stub" means in testing context? For example what does it mean in the comments below?

```
@Before
    public void stubAllExternalIntents() {
        // By default Espresso Intents does not **stub** any Intents. Stubbing needs to be setup before
        // every test run. In this case all external Intents will be blocked.
        intending(not(isInternal())).respondWith(new ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null));
    }
```

OR here:

```
@Test
    public void pickContactButton_click_SelectsPhoneNumber() {
        // **Stub** all Intents to ContactsActivity to return VALID_PHONE_NUMBER. Note that the Activity
        // is never launched and result is stubbed.
        intending(hasComponent(hasShortClassName(".ContactsActivity")))
                .respondWith(new ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,
                        ContactsActivity.createResultData(VALID_PHONE_NUMBER)));
```

Answer (score 1):

> A method stub or simply stub in software development is a piece of
>   code used to stand in for some other programming functionality. A stub
>   may simulate the behavior of existing code (such as a procedure on a
>   remote machine, such methods are often called mocks) or be a temporary
>   substitute for yet-to-be-developed code.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub